# How to convert from char array to string?

Tags: types

I'm so sorry my bad English.

I can't convert.. When i try to convert a char array to string, the string's values changed "True". I cant understand that.

Example Code:

[image: code]

The appearance of label5:

[image: Label]

Comment: Post your code on your post in code tags.

Comment: -1 for God's sake edit you post...

Comment: @Infer-On Why the -1? Is it just because his English isn't good enough to explain his problem in a way you can understand.?

Comment: Also include which language you are using (I'm assuming C++ CLI, but I can't be sure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `System::Convert::ToString`. Instead, simply use the string constructor that takes a `char[]` as a parameter:

```
String^ str2 = gcnew String(str);
```